# What is the difference between Constructor and Class function

Tags: delphi

In Delphi, What is the difference between Constructor and Class function to instantiate an object?

```
TPersonnel = class(TPersistent)
public
  class function Create: TPersonnel; overload;
  constructor Create(APersonelID: integer); overload;
end;

class function TPersonnel.Create: TPersonnel;
begin
  result := inherited Create;
end;

constructor TPersonnel.Create(APersonelID: integer);
begin
  inherited Create;
end;
```

I Know that class function Create will hide default constructor.

*Regardless constructor Create parameter*

Is there a reason that I should use the constructor?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there a reason that I should use the constructor?

Simply put, only a constructor can instantiate a new instance. A class function is not capable of creating a new instance.

For a class function to yield a new instance it **must** ultimately call a constructor in order to instantiate a new instance. And if you wish to write code that is executed when the instance is created, that should be placed in a constructor.

In your code's class function

```
class function TPersonnel.Create: TPersonnel;
begin
  Result := inherited Create;
end;
```

you are calling the inherited constructor with no parameters.

Comment: In my sample, Class function Create and Constructor Create both have a same job to do.

Comment: @Mohamad: Yes, but in your class function, you end up calling a constructor (of TPersistent), so in both cases a constructor is used to instantiate the class...

Comment: @Mohamad Only a constructor can instantiate a new instance.

Comment: @HeartWare, So in this case, no matter how Creator it is implemented. I have to use this case to implementing Singleton class and hide default constructor.

Comment: Only a constructor can instantiate a new instance

Comment: Nothing in the question mentions singletons.